# Starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

I have a tabactivity , and on click of each tab a new activity is invoked . In each activity I have an option to tap the NFC card and get the value. But the problem is When I am tapping the card on phone , a new activity is invoked without tabactivity as the parent. The code runs perfectly fine in a non tabactivity .

This is my code .

```
            adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
            tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
            ctx=this


Now from drop down option I select tag 


    if(position == 2){
                                        mMsisdn_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        mNFC_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        if(!adapter.isEnabled()){
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please activate NFC and press Back to return to the application!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                             startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                                         }

                                         else{
                                             mCustomizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(this);

                                            mCustomizeDialog.setTitle("NFC");
                                            mCustomizeDialog.setMessage("Please tap your NFC card");
                                            mCustomizeDialog.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            mCustomizeDialog.cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mCustomizeDialog.okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            if(mytag==null){
                                                                mCustomizeDialog.dismiss();

                                                            }else{
    //                                                      mEdtNFC.setText(NfcidValue);
                                                            mCustomizeDialog.dismiss();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                            });
                                            mCustomizeDialog.show();
                                         }



                            }



    /**
     * 
     * @param text
     * @param tag
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws FormatException
     */
    private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

        NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
        NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
        // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        // Enable I/O
        ndef.connect();
        // Write the message
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
        // Close the connection
        ndef.close();
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param text
     * @return
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String lang       = "en";
        byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
        byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        int    langLength = langBytes.length;
        int    textLength = textBytes.length;
        byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

        // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
        payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

        // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

        NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

        return recordNFC;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);  

            Log.d("NFC intent", intent.getAction());
        //  mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
//          System.out.println(myta);
              Log.d("NFC tag", mytag.toString());
           //   Log.d("NFC tag",bytesToHex(mytag.getId()).trim()); 
              NfcidValue = ConvertByteToHex.bytesToHex(mytag.getId()).trim();

              mEdtNFC.setText(NfcidValue);
           //   NfcidValue ="";
              Toast.makeText(this,"Tap was successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        WriteModeOff();
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    }*/

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void WriteModeOn(){
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
        writeMode = true;
        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void WriteModeOff(){
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
        writeMode = false;
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }
    }
```

This code works fine but I dont understand why a new activity is invoked when using it in tab activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try handling the NFC intents in the `TabActivity` instead.
Better yet (from Android UI design perspective) would be to redesign the app somewhat and use `Fragments` in a `ViewPager` within a single `Activity` (with an `ActionBar`). Then you never run into this problem.